# What does the commands `import gravity` and `import antigravity` do?

Tags: command-line

I want to know the use of `import gravity` and `import antigravity`. Is there any differences between these two commands?

`man import` shows:

> the  import  program  is a member of the ImageMagick(1) suite of
>   tools. Use it to capture some or all of an X server screen and save
>   the  image
>          to a file.

Did the `import gravity` and `import antigravity` commands capture the x server screen? If yes, then in what basis? And where is the captured image stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import gravity` lets you click on a window and saves a screenshot of that window in a PostScript file named `gravity` in your current folder.

`import antigravity` does the same thing  with a file named `antigravity`

Comment: Just about to answer that... more [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php). You need to run `import gravity.ps` to make it work better, then you should be able to just open the file with a click

Comment: Unless you are intending to print your screenshot, I would recommend `import gravity.png`. PNG is a lossless compressed format for bitmap images.